# R - read html files within a folder, count frequency, and export output

Tags: r, csv, automation, frequency, text-mining

I'm planning to use R to do some simple text mining tasks. Specifically, I would like to do the following:

1. Automatically read each html file within a folder, then
2. For each file, do frequency count of some particular words (e.g., "financial constraint" "oil export" etc.), then
3. Automatically write output to a csv. file using the following data structure (e.g., file 1 has "financial constraint" showing 3 times and "oil export" 4 times, etc.):

file_name count_financial_constraint count_oil_export
1 3 4
2 0 3
3 4 0
4 1 2

Can anyone please let me know where I should start, so far I think I've figured out how to clean html files and then do the count but I'm still not sure how to automate the process (I really need this as I have around 5 folders containing about 1000 html files within each)? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds more like a mini-project than a question about programming. You have 3 separate questions in your lists. Every question you asked has several answers right here on overflow. Do search around, write your script, and ask when you run into trouble. That's where you should start in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gethtml<-function(path=".") {
  files<-list.files(path)
  setwd(path)
  html<-grepl("*.html",files)
  files<-files[html]
  htmlcount<-vector()
  for (i in files) {
    htmlcount[i]<- ##### add function that reads html file and counts it
  }
  return(sum(htmlcount))
}
```

Comment: thanks! let me try this out, I appreciate for leading me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

R is not intended for doing rigorous text parsing. Subsequently, the tools for such tasks are limited. If you insist on doing it with R then you better get familiar with regular expressions and have a look at [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/htmltotext-extracting-text-from-html-via-xpath/).

However, I highly recommend using Python with the [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library, which is specifically designed for this task.

Comment: thanks, I agree, but what I'm dealing with is fairly standard business documents, and in fact, I've been using what you recommended "htmlToText()" for my text mining task

Comment: I didn't realize you just wanted to automate the file access.